# Why do I keep getting an error when I use "all: " in my Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to make a simple makefile but whenever I use the "all" target and try to complie I keep recieving an error that says another character was expected before the colon.
The error I keep receiving (bottom panel) and the code itself (top panel):
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JByNv.png)

I've tried adding a space and changing it to a semicolon but neither work. Please let me know why I'm getting this error and how I can fix it.

Comment: [Don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: But I can say that you completely misunderstand makefiles and how they work and are used. What learning material are you using to learn about makefiles?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The makefile should be named Makefile, NOT Makefile.c.

make isnt finding the makefile since its badly named and then is trying compile sources that are not actual c source files

Comment: makefile not Makefile